# Pulling data from a form?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a script that will pull a submitted input & use it to send an alert based on what was chosen, though whenever I do this it does not seem to be corresponding.

Any answers?

Javascript:

```
<script language="Javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function checkForm() {
        alert(form.option.value);
        if (form.option.value == "one") {
            alert("Test 1");
        } else if (form.option.value == "two") {
            alert("Test 2");
        } else {
            alert("Test 3");
        }
    }
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<form onsubmit="checkForm()">
    <select>
        <option value="one">One</option>
        <option value="two">Two</option>
        <option value="three">Three</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="option">
</form>
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: I get nothing in return, that's what makes me think I might be messing up somewhere in the "form.option.value" area, but I don't know for sure.

Comment: Try alerting out a static string like `alert("test");`. See if that shows up. If not, that means the function isn't being called and it could be a scope issue.

Comment: I recieved the alert, it just seems to blank out once I have (form.option.value);

Answer (score 1):

Your current code is not working cause you will get an error in your method:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: form is not defined
```

You need to obtain a handle to the correct elements. `form` is not just going to exist and `option.value` is not correct either.

Get your relevant elements as seen below:

```
<script language="Javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function checkForm() {
        var form = document.forms[0];
        var selectElement = form.querySelector('select');
        var selectedValue = selectElement.value;

        alert(selectedValue);
        if (selectedValue == "one") {
            alert("Test 1");
        } else if (selectedValue == "two") {
            alert("Test 2");
        } else {
            alert("Test 3");
        }
    }
</script>
```

---

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/He5xA/)

---

In addition for completeness and as already mentioned in another answer, if you want to prevent the submit at some point update the form tag to `onsubmit="return checkForm()"` and add `return false;` in your `checkForm()` method at the relevant location, i.e: after one of the alerts.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm still getting into javascript but every bit helps. props. :)

Comment: @AnthonyTobuscus: No worries, glad to help :) If you need some useful resources on JavaScrip the official [**JavaScript MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/JavaScript) is a great start. In addition running code you want to test or play around with in tools like [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/) using browser debugger tools is a great way to find out about any possible issues.

Answer (score 0):

Change `onsubmit="checkForm()"` to `onsubmit="return checkForm()"`

And start by returning `false` from that function. That will prevent refreshing the page.

PS: and add `debugger` at the top of the function to trigger whatever debugger your browser have.